# How to get the apple touch icon from a site and if it doesn't exist then show favicon?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to grab the apple touch icon from a website (from my understanding *most* sites have their icon stored at `website.com/apple-touch-icon.png`) and if there is a 404 or if the image doesn't exist then use Google favicon grabber (`https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain_url=google.com`) to show the favicon of the site.

Would that be possible with js/jquery?

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking this instead of just trying to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the url of an image to the touch icon url, and use the `onerror` event to change it to the favicon url.

```
function getImage(url) {
    image.src = url + "/apple-touch-icon.png";
    image.onerror = function() {
        image.src = "https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain_url=" + url;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9b1fkay/) (remember to include http:// before urls in the input box)

However, some websites use a url other than "apple-touch-icon.png", so you may want to use multiple error functions in order to always get the apple touch icon.

Also, some websites (like google) return a 1px x 1px image for images that don't exist, meaning this won't work.